# Value of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)' cannot be converted to 'String'. in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting Asyn calls but having a problem unboxing my results. Here is the error info that I got : **Value of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)' cannot be converted to 'String'.**
Can someone help to achieve this. This is my code that I used:

```
Private Sub Download_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'GET DOWNLOAD URL
    Dim download_url As String = Download_HttpClient(space_id, file_id)

    'ACCESS URL THROUGH GOOGLE CHROME
    Dim proc As New ProcessStartInfo()
    proc.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
    proc.Arguments = "/c start chrome " + download_url
    Process.Start(proc)
End Sub

Public Async Function Download_HttpClient(ByVal spaceId As String, fileId As String) As Task(Of String)
    Dim cookieContainer As New CookieContainer
    Dim httpClientHandler As New HttpClientHandler
    httpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    httpClientHandler.UseCookies = True
    httpClientHandler.CookieContainer = cookieContainer
    Dim httpClient As New HttpClient(httpClientHandler)

    'GET LOGIN CREDENTIALS
    Dim login_url As String = host + "/common/Authentication.json"
    Dim login_parameter As String = "?id=" + user_id + "&pw=" + password
    Dim login_response As HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.GetAsync(login_url + login_parameter)
    Dim login_contents As String = Await login_response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    'MessageBox.Show(login_contents)

    'GET DOWNLOAD ID
    Dim download_url As String = host + "/contentsmanagement/SingleContentsDownloadApi.json"
    Dim download_param As String = "?fileId=" + file_id + "&spaceId=" + space_id + "&type=alive"
    Dim download_response As HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.GetAsync(download_url + download_param)
    Dim download_contents As String = Await download_response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    Dim downloadId As String = Nothing
    Dim map As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    map = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(download_contents)
    map.TryGetValue("id", downloadId)
    'MessageBox.Show(downloadId)
    'set DOWNLOAD URL
    Dim url As String = host + "/contentsmanagement/ContentsDownloadApi.json?id=" + downloadId
    Return url

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function is declared `Async` and returns a `Task(Of T)`, you need to `Await` it when you call it in order to get the `T` object produced by the `Task`, i.e. this:

```vb
Dim download_url As String = Download_HttpClient(space_id, file_id)
```

needs to be changed to this:

```vb
Dim download_url As String = Await Download_HttpClient(space_id, file_id)
```

You can only use `Await` in a method that is, itself, declared `Async` though. That means that this:

```vb
Private Sub Download_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

needs to be changed to this:

```vb
Private Async Sub Download_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

Note that you should only ever use `Async Sub` for event handlers and otherwise use `Async Function`.

I would generally recommend some reading on `Async`/`Await` but it is a somewhat advanced topic. As a general rule, if you need to call an existing `Async` function, e.g. `HttpClient.GetAsync`, then you need to make your own methods `Async` too.

If you have a `Sub` like this:

```vb
Private Sub SomeMethod()
```

and you call it like this:

```vb
SomeMethod()
```

then that would become this:

```vb
Private Async Function SomeMethodAsync() As Task
```

and this:

```vb
Await SomeMethodAsync()
```

The exception is an event handler, which I already demonstrated above. They must be a `Sub` and you don't call them directly.

Similarly, if you have a `Function` like this:

```vb
Private Function SomeMethod() As T
```

and you call it like this:

```vb
Dim result As T = SomeMethod()
```

then that would become this:

```vb
Private Async Function SomeMethodAsync() As Task(Of T)
```

and this:

```vb
Dim result As T = Await SomeMethodAsync()
```

If you have a method that is not `Async` and you want to call an `Async` method in it, you have to make your method `Async` and use `Await`, then make any methods that call it `Async` and use `Await` in them, and on up the chain until you get to your event handler(s). This is why it is generally recommended that, if you're going to use `Async` at all, you use it pretty much everywhere.

If making everything `Async` is too onerous then you can call an asynchronous method synchronously and get the result of the `Task` returned, e.g. this:

```vb
Dim download_url As String = Download_HttpClient(space_id, file_id)
```

becomes this:

```vb
Dim download_url_task As Task(Of String) = Download_HttpClient(space_id, file_id)
Dim download_url As String = download_url_task.Result
```

or just this:

```vb
Dim download_url As String = Download_HttpClient(space_id, file_id).Result
```